# Modified History of Specific User on Specific Excel File in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have an Excel file in SharePoint site, every 10th day of the month, I am using Power Automate to send report update reminder email to team members.

I wish to track if all team members updated the Excel file in subsequent 8 days and prompt the member and myself of No Action Taken.

Is there ootb in SharePoint? Or, is there a way to do so using Power Automate?

Comment: Yes, there is.  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Hi Skin, I had not tried any, as I am not really profession with SharePoint or Power Automate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flow triggered on the 18th of every month to view the people who modified a specific document in the past 8 days. If there is no modification, an email will be sent to remind you and the people who have not modified it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Xyza_MSFT. May I ask if it is possible just send to person that is not yet updated/modified the Excel file in the 8-day, instead of prompt to all team members.